# how to display validation error message out from the textfield in flutter

Tags: flutter, validation

[image]

how to display "this field is required" message out from the box. this message will display on button click.

here is the textfield code

-------------------EDITED QUESTION-------------------

Here is your code and modified it by adding one more textformfield

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';



class ExperimentApp extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      theme: ThemeData(
        scaffoldBackgroundColor: Colors.white,
      ),
      home: ExperimentHome(),
    );
  }
}

class ExperimentHome extends StatelessWidget {
  final GlobalKey<FormFieldState> formFieldKey = GlobalKey();
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      body: Center(
        child: Row(
          children: [
            Expanded(
              child: Padding(
                padding: const EdgeInsets.all(8.0),
                child: RoundedInputField(
                  formFieldKey: formFieldKey,
                  icon: Icons.edit,
                  labelText: 'Label',
                  validate: (value) {
                    if (value == null || value.isEmpty) {
                      return "This field is required";
                    }
                    return null;
                  },
                ),
              ),
            ),
//this is one more TextFormField
            RoundedInputField(
                  formFieldKey: formFieldKey,
                  icon: Icons.edit,
                  labelText: 'Label1',
                  validate: (value) {
                    if (value == null || value.isEmpty) {
                      return "This field is required";
                    }
                    return null;
                  },
                ),
            
            IconButton(
              icon: Icon(Icons.check),
              onPressed: () {
                // you need to call `.validate` to actually validate the field.
                formFieldKey.currentState.validate();
              },
            )
          ],
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}

class RoundedInputField extends StatelessWidget {
  final IconData icon;
  final FormFieldValidator<String> validate;
  final String labelText;

  final GlobalKey<FormFieldState> formFieldKey;

  // (before flutter 2.0) drop `required`
  const RoundedInputField({
    Key key,
    @required this.formFieldKey,
    
    
    @required this.labelText,
    @required this.icon,
    @required this.validate,
  }) : super(key: key);

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return TextFormField(
      key: formFieldKey,
      validator: validate,
      decoration: InputDecoration(
        icon: Icon(
          icon,
          color: Colors.blue,
        ),
        labelText: labelText,
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

this is error

```
════════ Exception caught by rendering library ═════════════════════════════════
RenderBox was not laid out: RenderTransform#3842d NEEDS-LAYOUT NEEDS-PAINT
'package:flutter/src/rendering/box.dart':
Failed assertion: line 1940 pos 12: 'hasSize'

The relevant error-causing widget was
TextFormField-[LabeledGlobalKey<FormFieldState<dynamic>>#a4b32]
lib\abc.dart:87
════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════

════════ Exception caught by widgets library ═══════════════════════════════════
Multiple widgets used the same GlobalKey.
════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════

════════ Exception caught by widgets library ═══════════════════════════════════
Multiple widgets used the same GlobalKey.
════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════
```

and it shows a plain white screen as output

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to use a `GlobalKey<FormFieldState>` and actually call `.validate` on the field to validate the field.

When you call `.validate`, the `TextFormField` will validate the field and show the error message if the validate method returns a `String`.

More on `TextFormField`: https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/material/TextFormField-class.html

Code Sample (there are some syntatic differences as you seem to be using an older version of dart):

```dart
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

void main() async {
  runApp(ExperimentApp());
}

class ExperimentApp extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      theme: ThemeData(
        scaffoldBackgroundColor: Colors.white,
      ),
      home: ExperimentHome(),
    );
  }
}

class ExperimentHome extends StatelessWidget {
  final GlobalKey<FormFieldState> formFieldKey = GlobalKey();
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      body: Center(
        child: Row(
          children: [
            Expanded(
              child: Padding(
                padding: const EdgeInsets.all(8.0),
                child: RoundedInputField(
                  formFieldKey: formFieldKey,
                  icon: Icons.edit,
                  labelText: 'Label',
                  validate: (value) {
                    if (value == null || value.isEmpty) {
                      return "This field is required";
                    }
                    return null;
                  },
                ),
              ),
            ),
            IconButton(
              icon: Icon(Icons.check),
              onPressed: () {
                // you need to call `.validate` to actually validate the field.
                formFieldKey.currentState!.validate();
              },
            )
          ],
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}

class RoundedInputField extends StatelessWidget {
  final IconData icon;
  final FormFieldValidator<String> validate;
  final String labelText;

  final GlobalKey<FormFieldState> formFieldKey;

  // (before flutter 2.0) drop `required`
  const RoundedInputField({
    Key? key,
    required this.formFieldKey,
    required this.labelText,
    required this.icon,
    required this.validate,
  }) : super(key: key);

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return TextFormField(
      key: formFieldKey,
      validator: validate,
      decoration: InputDecoration(
        icon: Icon(
          icon,
          color: Colors.blue,
        ),
        labelText: labelText,
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: but it's not working when i add more than 1 textfields

Comment: Could you give more details, maybe a minimal code sample to reproduce your error?

Comment: please check it now!

Comment: It looks like you are reusing the same GlobalKey. You need to have one global key for each textformfield

Comment: when i did that, it doesn't display "this is required field" when click on button

Comment: i changed row to column and added "key: formFieldKey," after scaffold

Comment: You need a new GlobalKey for each, each time you want to validate anyone of them, you should also call .validate on the corresponding key. If you happen to want to validate all at once, you can also check the Form widget

Comment: i have used Form widget too, but didn't workk!

Comment: Hi, the problem is still that you are using formFieldKey for two different fields. You need something like formFieldKey1 snd formFieldKey2 and pass them each to their corresponding fields. Then, inside the IconButton call both formFieldKey1.currentState.validate and formFieldKey2.currentState.validate

Comment: i uploaded the answer. it works perfectly. thanks for ur help!

Answer (score 1):

This will work for you.

```
 decoration: InputDecoration(
                                      focusedBorder: UnderlineInputBorder(
                                        borderSide: BorderSide(
                                            color: Colors.anyColor,
                                            width: 2),
                                      ),
                                      focusedErrorBorder: UnderlineInputBorder(
                                        borderSide: BorderSide(
                                            color: Colors.anyColor,
                                            width: 2),
                                      ),
                                      errorBorder:
                                          (value.isEmpty)
                                              ? UnderlineInputBorder(
                                                  borderSide: BorderSide(
                                                      color: Colors.anyColor),
                                                )
                                              : InputBorder.none,
                                      errorText:
                                          (value.isEmpty)
                                              ? "Minimum 3 characters required"
                                              : null,
                                      errorStyle: anyTextStyle(),
                                      hintText: "Name",
                                      hintStyle:
                                          anyTextStyle()),
```

Answer (score 0):

Finally I got the solution! Here it works perfectly.

`TextFormField` widget:

```
import 'package:attendance_system_app/text_field_container.dart';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

class RoundedInputField extends StatelessWidget {
  final String hintText;
  final IconData icon;
  final ValueChanged<String> onChanged;
  final TextEditingController controller;
  final double fontsize;
  final FormFieldValidator<String> validate;
  final String errortext;
  final String labelText;
  final GlobalKey<FormFieldState> formFieldKey;
  //final  onsaved;

  const RoundedInputField(
      {Key key,
      this.labelText,
      this.formFieldKey,
      this.errortext,
      this.hintText,
      this.icon,
      this.validate,
      this.onChanged,
      this.controller,
      this.fontsize})
      : super(key: key);

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return TextFormField(
      decoration: InputDecoration(
        labelText: labelText,
        fillColor: Colors.blue[50],
        border: OutlineInputBorder(
          borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(29.0),
        ),
      ),
      validator: validate,
      controller: controller,
      maxLength: 5,
    );
  }
}
```

And here you can call the widget.

```
class JafPersonals extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _JafPersonalState createState() => _JafPersonalState();
}

class _JafPersonalState extends State<JafPersonals> {
  TextEditingController _applicantName = new TextEditingController();
  TextEditingController _fatherName = new TextEditingController();
  final GlobalKey<FormState> _formkey = GlobalKey<FormState>();

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return new Scaffold(
      drawer: new AdminDrawerCode(),
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: Image.asset(
          "assets/image/company_logo.png",
          height: 140,
          width: 280,
        ),

        //automaticallyImplyLeading: false,
        backgroundColor: Colors.white,
        iconTheme: IconThemeData(color: Colors.blue, size: 20),
        //leading: new Icon(Icons.menu,color: Colors.blue,),
        actions: <Widget>[
          IconButton(
            icon: Icon(Icons.notifications, color: Colors.blue, size: 26),
            onPressed: () {
              // do something
            },
          )
        ],
      ),
      body: Form(
        key: _formkey,
        child: ListView(
          padding: EdgeInsets.all(16),
          children: [
            Text(" Employee Bio Data",
                style: TextStyle(
                    fontSize: 30,
                    fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
                    color: Colors.blue[900])),
            SizedBox(
              height: 20,
            ),
            Text(" Personal data",
                style: TextStyle(
                    fontSize: 25,
                    fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
                    color: Colors.blue[900])),
            SizedBox(
              height: 20,
            ),
            RoundedInputField(
              labelText: 'Applicant name',
              controller: _applicantName,
              validate: (value) {
                if (value.length < 4) {
                  return 'Enter at least 4 characters';
                } else {
                  return null;
                }
              },
            ),
            SizedBox(height: 10),
            RoundedInputField(
              labelText: 'Father name',
              controller: _applicantName,
              validate: (value) {
                if (value.length < 4) {
                  return 'Enter at least 4 characters';
                } else {
                  return null;
                }
              },
            ),
            RoundedButton(
              text: 'Submit',
              press: () {
                final isvalid = _formkey.currentState.validate();
                if (isvalid) {
                  _formkey.currentState.save();
                  Navigator.push(context,
                      MaterialPageRoute(builder: (context) => JafFamily()));
                }
              },
            ),
          ],
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```